# Div height 100% causing overflow issues

Tags: css, html, height

I recently decided to ditch tables and go with a div solution on this new project, however I'm having a really weird issue when setting a div within another div to 100% without it causing overflow equal to the height of the div's above it. It's acting like the browser isn't aware of the div's above it occupying that space.

I have a wrapper div with a fixed width and height set to 100%, within that is 3 column divs (left, mid and right) in the mid column I have 3 div's, the top 2 have fixed heights 90px and the 3rd is set to 100% to fill the rest of the content area but it's breaking out of the wrapper div and causing exactly 180px overflow. I setup this simple layout on JSFiddle: [Height: 100% Div Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/KtUgF/1/)

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div style="background-color:fuchsia; height: 90px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
        <div style="background-color:purple; height: 90px; width: 998px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="background-color:blue; height: 90px; width: 998px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="background-color:black; height: 100%; width: 50%;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div style="background-color:fuchsia; height: 90px;" class="right">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will notice the black div is breaking out of the yellow (mid) div, this should not happen! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is what the table solution looks like of what I'm trying to do:

<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <tr>
  <td style="height: 90px">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="height: 90px">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="height: 100%">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>

Why is the div method so much more difficult?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KtUgF/7/

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I don't see any update on that fiddle?

Comment: This is the layout I created http://beforethecode.net/projects/ngs/ so you can see what I'm trying to pull off here. It's nothing groundbreaking or complex it should be very straight forward but trying to recreate this table layout with div's has been a nightmare so far.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying a height of 100% on the black div, which ends up being relative to its parent (`.mid`) which also happens to contain the other elements that you gave 90px of height to. You have to account for those two siblings.

You can do this by using the [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) notation, though mobile browser support is bad and the function isn't supported in IE8 & below.

http://jsfiddle.net/KtUgF/5/

You can also use a negative top-margin on the black div equal to the sum of both of its siblings (180px):

http://jsfiddle.net/yrfnc/

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrift, sadly I need IE8 support and the top-margin setting feels like such a hack to do something pretty straight forward (I would think). This black div happens to by main content area so once I start filling it with data I would have to pad all that down +180px to counter the negative top margin setting.

Comment: Then you'll need to use JS or re-consider your layout

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue

```
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score -1):

Any reason why you can't just add overflow: hidden to the ".mid" div?

```
<div class="mid" style="overflow:hidden">
```

or

```
.mid {
    float: left;
    width: 998px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Because that area is my MAIN content div. And I need to place a lot of other UI inside it. By simply setting overflow to hidden I would be hiding my content! I need it to be true to the actual space on the screen so it can expand vertically even if needed and not have the scrolling inside the div itself.

Comment: Then you would still need to pad as you mentioned for the negative margin trick. If you don't want the black div the same height as its parent you should remove the 100% height. If your goal is to style the left half of the yellow div, there are always other ways of accomplishing that (even using a background image).

Comment: I want it to take up the entire available space on the screen... But aside from that another thing I noticed, why isn't it expanding the parent div's to match the overflow of the black div? I did this test on fiddle to show what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/KtUgF/6/ I would be fine if everything else grew with the data! this isn't even set to 100% anymore. It's just filled with BR tags

Comment: Height is relative to the parent. "height: 100%" means use the same height as your parent, not fill up the remaining space. In your case, you have 100% all the way up the chain which means it will be the same size as the window. In the newest fiddle, you took 100% off of the black div and now it grows as large as the content. The other divs are still set at 100% height and stay at the window size.

Comment: Apparently only to the parent div and ignores the actual document/overflow size? because the body/html is expanding beyond therefor 100% should also be relative to THAT also right? tables work this way why not div's?

Comment: A div's height and its overflow height are different for at least one reason (and one that is unique to divs, not tables): scrolling. When you pick a size for a div, it honors it and your only choices for what to do with the overflow are included in the css property: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html. You either show it OUTSIDE the box, hide it, or scroll it. This also applies to all parent divs as well, their overflow isn't included in their height either.